# detect string between brackets using regex

Tags: python-2.7

How can i use regex in python to detect in one file only the stings between the brackets?
So If i have some text like this:

```
</seg>
<src>Sono stati riportati casi di (sgomberi forzati) e violazioni dei diritti umani da parte della polizia, ma su scala minore rispetto agli anni precedenti.</src>
```

and I want to detect only (sgomberi forzati)

I use the

```
for line  in file.readlines():
    m=re.compile('\((.*?)\)', re.DOTALL).findall(line)
    print m
```

but it does not print  what I need: it prints also brackets empty like this

```
[]
[u'sgomberi forzati']
```

Comment: _"but it does not return what I need"_. Makes sense. It's not returning anything because you don't have a `return` statement anywhere in your code. If you mean "It doesn't print what I need": it [works for me](http://ideone.com/oZMDQ1). Unless you want it to print something other than `['regional economies', 'transportation']`? Please describe what kind of output you expect.

Comment: yes, It doesn't print what I need

Comment: Please describe what kind of output you expect.

Comment: what I need is the srings between the brackets, i.e (regional economies), (transportation).

Comment: Yes, and that is exactly what is being printed. So you don't actually have a problem, then?

Comment: the code used by me prints also brackets empty

Answer (score 1):

Escape your `()` as follows:

`m = re.compile('\((.*?)\)', re.DOTALL).findall(line)`

Comment: @user3573552, Wait a minute, I swear you just had `'((.*?))'`. You are someone else changed your code. o.O

Comment: The slashes were present but not visible in the first version of the code. When it was put in code blocks, they appeared.